# How to convert dates in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to convert this date format:

```
18/11/2011 7:00
```

to this:

```
2011.11.18. 7:00
```

in excel? Can it be done with a macro or is it not necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `"custom format"`. Select range, right-click, select "format cells" and under number select "custom" and enter this in "Type" box

> yyyy.mm.dd. h:mm

Comment: `yyyy.mm.dd. h:mm`  Don't forget the extra dot after the day.

Comment: good spot mischab! I missed that - amended